# Pixel pitch of a monitor

Tags: external-display, pixels

How can the pixel pitch of a monitor be double another monitor if they both have the same resolution and are the same size? E.g., Acer B6 Series B286HK and ASUS PB287Q.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_density

Comment: @g2mk: Yeah, I read that.  I don't see how the constraint of area and pixel count doesn't make this impossible?  Do the monitors use a different configuration?

Comment: Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_pitch it explains the different pixel placement technologies that determine how Pixel Pitch is measured.